# Is it possible to return a different object onComplete than what the Stream emits?

Tags: dart

I have an API that returns a `Stream<int> uploadFile()`, where `int` represents the number of bytes uploaded, but then I'd like, upon completion, to have it return a completely different type - in this case, a `String` of the upload file's URL. Is that possible?

```
Stream<int> uploadFile(File file) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider reading the help center for guidance on asking questions. It's not clear from your question, what context we're running in. Consider adding a code snippet to make it easier for the community to engage in your question

Answer (score 2):

The short answer, is *no*, it is not possible to do that *explicitly*.

You have a few options, and I'll highlight *my* preference:

1. Return either `dynamic` or `Object`, and indicate (to the user) that the emitted event will be of type `int` while in progress, and `String` once complete. This relies on doing a number of `is` checks, and I wouldn't personally choose this option:

   ```
   uploadFile().listen((progress) {
     if (progress is int) {

     } else if (progress is String) {

     }
   });
   ```
2. Return a wrapper class, for example, `UploadProgress`:

   ```
   abstract class UploadProgress {
     int get progressPercent;
     String get uploadUrl;
   }

   Stream<UploadProgress> uploadFile() { ... }
   ```
3. My preference: Return a wrapper class that exposes a `Stream`:

   ```
   abstract class FileUpload {
     Stream<int> get progress;
     Future<String> get url;
   }

   FileUpload uploadFile() { ... }
   ```

The last option will make it clear you can listen to the `progress` field, or simply await `url` to wait for completion of the upload. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that really helps.  I'd like to go with option 3, can you give an example on how to feed the progress stream and url from within uploadFile?